# Discrete approximations of Riemannian manifolds and topological complexity

Tags: metric-spaces, geometric-topology, discrete-geometry

It's known (due to Perelman) that in class of Alexandrov spaces of fixed dimension and bounded from below curvature Gromov-Hausdorff distance separates homeomorphism types — every $\epsilon$-close to $X$ space will be homeomorphic to $X$ for some $\epsilon$.

Well, if we have some finite metric space $X_{\delta}$ which is $\epsilon/2$-close to $X$, then $(X_{\delta}, n, C)$ define homeomorphism type of, say, compact Riemannian manifold, where $n$ is dimension and $C$ is lower curvature bound.

Now let's fix $C$ once for all (take $-1$, for example) and call finite metric space $X_{\delta}$ *a model* of a manifold $X$ if for some $\epsilon$ the only manifold $\epsilon$-close to $X_{\delta}$ is $X$ with some metric. We can define two functions on homeomorphism (diffeo, if dim > 4, thanks to Grove-Peterson-Wu) classes of $n$-dimensional manifolds: $min \, |X_{\delta}|$ and $min \, k: X_{\delta} \to \Bbb R^k$ for isometric embedding into real space with some norm, where minimum is taken over all models. It seems appropriate to me to call first one metric complexity $mCom(X)$ and second one — virtual dimension $vdim(X)$.

So, my questions are

- are there some bounds on $mCom$ in terms of something like LS category or topological complexity (i. e. minimal cardinality of open cover over which $eval: X^I \to X \times X$ has local sections?
- can $vdim(X)$ be less than dimension of $X$?
- what is, for example, $mCom(S^1 \times S^1)$ and what is the model? (I guess that for all surfaces answers should be derivable from known results)